# Where are android drivers located in the system?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, asus-eee-pad-transformer, usb-drivers

Specifically, I'm looking for the drivers responsible for the tf101 and sl101 detachable and slideout keyboards in ICS.

But in general, where are the drivers located inside the Android OS itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're most of the time baked right into the monolithic Linux kernel (or sometimes available as loadable .ko kernel modules located in /system/lib/modules/). Note: Linux kernel modules are build-specific and cannot be interchanged across devices, different firmware versions.

See the Wikipedia entry for [Linux kernel modules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadable_kernel_module)

Comment: so my keyboard module is likely built into the kernel and If I wanted to get it I would have to have the stock kernel?

Comment: Not quite clear what your use case is here... Do you want to build/have your own kernel? There are multiple ways for keyboards to be attached to linux: Bluetooth-HID, USB-HID (human interface device abstraction layer) and probably built-in hardware keyboards with their own driver. They should be available in Asus' source distribution for the TF101, though. You cannot just take the precompiled stuff and install it into a different linux kernel.

Comment: I've got Ubuntu running on the sl101 and the slidout keyboard is not working. I have no doubt that it is a driver /kernel problem but .... it is completely disapointing to me if I can't get the keyboard working... I've already been watingn almost two years to get ubuntu on this thing... every day is so depressing that this doesn't work... i have to get it working somehow... either get the driver for linux or make my own driver whatever the solution is

Comment: Ok. Now things become a lot clearer. You would need to do some kernel patching most probably (integrate the sl101 kb driver into ubuntu's kernel source and recompile. This is very close to development and sadly off topic (Ubuntu porting)... I guess. Already saw your post on XDA, goog luck! Keep us informed! :-)

Comment: I want to locate the USB driver for transformer tf101 , where can I find it ?